# Aggregate query result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have collection with documents like this one:

```
{  
   "_id": 1,
   "people": [  
      {  
         "name": "Bob",
         "age": "15"
      },
      {  
         "name": "Alice",
         "age": "18"
      }
   ]
}
```

My query is:

```
db.groups.aggregate({ $match: { "_id": 1 }}, { $project: { "_id": 0, "people.name": 1 } })
```

This query returns:

```
{  
   "people": [  
      {  
         "name": "Bob"
      },
      {  
         "name": "Alice"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I need the result like:

```
{ "names": [ "Bob", "Alice" ] }
```

Which parameters should I add to the .aggregate() function?

Comment: No need to use `$map` here... Try this `.groups.aggregate({ $match: { "_id": 1 }}, { $project: { "_id": 0, "names": "$people.name" } })`

Comment: Thanks! It's helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
db.groups.aggregate({ $match: { "_id": 1 }}, { $project: { "_id": 0, "names": "$people.name" } })
```